# Order of classes to improve performance accessing a file with buffered readers

Tags: java, performance, inputstream

I have a input stream returned by an http call. I need to parse it as json and I am using the library "simplejson".

Because the json parser accepts as input a Reader, I have to transform the input stream. I have the following two options and I would like to know if there are obvious reasons to prefer one over the other.

**Option 1**: Wrap the input stream with an instance of InputStreamReader and then wrap the reader with a BufferedReader:

```
jsonObject = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(method.getResponseBodyAsStream(), "UTF-8")));
```

**Option 2**: Wrap the input stream with a BufferedInputStream and then wrap it with an InputStreamReader:

```
jsonObject = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(
        new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()), "UTF-8"));
```

The first option seems better but I am wondering if I can end up buffering the response twice: both the BufferedReader and the InputStreamReader have methods to read from a buffer.

I checked better the code in the JSON Parser and it looks like it is using the method in Reader to get an array of character:

```
  /**
   * Refills the input buffer.
   *
   * @return      <code>false</code>, iff there was new input.
   * 
   * @exception   java.io.IOException  if any I/O-Error occurs
   */
  private boolean zzRefill() throws java.io.IOException {

    /* first: make room (if you can) */
    if (zzStartRead > 0) {
      System.arraycopy(zzBuffer, zzStartRead,
                       zzBuffer, 0,
                       zzEndRead-zzStartRead);

      /* translate stored positions */
      zzEndRead-= zzStartRead;
      zzCurrentPos-= zzStartRead;
      zzMarkedPos-= zzStartRead;
      zzStartRead = 0;
    }

    /* is the buffer big enough? */
    if (zzCurrentPos >= zzBuffer.length) {
      /* if not: blow it up */
      char newBuffer[] = new char[zzCurrentPos*2];
      System.arraycopy(zzBuffer, 0, newBuffer, 0, zzBuffer.length);
      zzBuffer = newBuffer;
    }

    /* finally: fill the buffer with new input */
    int numRead = zzReader.read(zzBuffer, zzEndRead,
                                            zzBuffer.length-zzEndRead);

    if (numRead > 0) {
      zzEndRead+= numRead;
      return false;
    }
    // unlikely but not impossible: read 0 characters, but not at end of stream    
    if (numRead == 0) {
      int c = zzReader.read();
      if (c == -1) {
        return true;
      } else {
        zzBuffer[zzEndRead++] = (char) c;
        return false;
      }     
    }

    // numRead < 0
    return true;
  }
```

I think that the answer is that the BufferedReader is not necessary at all and that it does make a difference to use it because using it we would buffer the stream twice.

Comment: Test and measure. You will almost certainly find that it makes no difference whatsoever, due to the entire request having been buffered before the method got invoked.

Comment: @EJP - I have to add that the response in my case can contain "logging messages" and so it can be big. It is also difficult to measure the performance in regard to the use of memory unless I spend a quite amount of time preparing the tests.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you should test and measure, nor my prediction as to the result.

Comment: I understand your point, but I was hoping to receive an answer based on the knowledge of the algorithm, if this knowledge is enough to do an estimate of the performance.

Comment: I've already stated the algorithm. The entire response has almost certainly already been buffered. Hence my prediction.

Comment: @EJP I do not fully understand your answer. My main concern was avoiding to buffer the stream twice. I get that the stream is probably already buffered but wouldn't be a problem to buffer it again if it is not necessary ?

Answer (score 0):

`BufferedReader` is somewhat heavy-weight, as it needs to understand and handle line separators.  Your case doesn't seem to call for that, so you may want to go with `InputStreamReader` on top of `BufferedInputStream`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I won't set it immediately as accepted waiting for other feedbacks.

Comment: Agreed. @MarcoAltieri You don't actually need to buffer at all. If buffering is required the library will handle it transparently. Else it would require you to supply some sort of buffered reader, which it doesn't.

Comment: @Brian: I must admit that the question about the *need* for buffering in the first place didn't occur to me, and the point you make is sort of plausible -- but I wouldn't bet that the underlying code would do its own buffering in any given case, and I, for one, would rather that it left it to the client code's discretion.

Comment: @Brian When you say "the library" do you mean the Json parser ? In that case, I checked and the library does not do any buffering. I think that it makes sense because only who is calling the parser knows if the input stream is already buffered or not and you do not want to buffer it twice

Comment: It only needs to 'understand and handle line separators' if you are calling `readLine()`. As the JSON parser clearly takes a `Reader` rather than a `BufferedReader`, either it isn't calling `readLine()` or it is interposing its own `BUfferedReader`. In neither case does it make the slgihtest bit of difference which one the OP should use.

Comment: @MarcoAltieri Yes by "the library" I mean the JSON parser. As you've found out by yourself, it does its own buffering, thus rendering any intermediate buffering unnecessary/redundant. If one would want to go "back" a few characters while reading from a `Reader`, then a `BufferedReader` makes sense of course. If not, well then it doesn't. Anyways, you've found the answer to your question pretty much on your own and that's a job well done imho.

Comment: @EJP: Nope.  As is evident from code from at least one JDK, `BufferedReader` needs to concern itself with line separators *all the time*, because you *might want to* call `readLine()`.